# Checkbox + Jquery Проблема со свойством checked

Tags: jquery, html, css

Пытаюсь узнать о состоянии CheckBox через jQuery, пытаюсь так:
$('#checkin6').attr('checked')
 Возвращает из консоли undefined, если прописываю в консоль:
$('#checkin6')
то все верно, возвращает тот< input> который надо, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо через мето свойство, Ваш вариант возвращает состояние при загрузке.

```
$('#checkin6').is(':checked')
```